# If/else error message to PHP MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple query (AJAX). I noticed that if the `$insert_stmt` does not execute I still got a success message.

```
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `alerte` (`nom_alerte`, `country`, `date_debut_alerte`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
  $insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', $alert_name, $country, $start_alert_date);
  $insert_stmt->execute();
  $reponse = 'success';
} else {
  $reponse = 'Sorry, a database error occurred; please try later';
}
echo json_encode(["reponse" => $reponse]);
```

I would like to know if there is a way of adding another if/else statement to verify the execute

I tried something like that, but I am not sure it is good coding:

```
if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `alerte` (`nom_alerte`, `country`, `date_debut_alerte`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
  $insert_stmt->bind_param('sss', $alert_name, $country, $start_alert_date);

  // inserted part if/else check
  if (! $insert_stmt->execute()) {
    $reponse = 'Sorry, a database error occurred; please try later';
  } else {
    $reponse = 'success';
  }
} else {
  $reponse = 'Sorry, a database error occurred; please try later';
}
```

Is someone able to tell me if it is suitable or if there is a better way?

Comment: $insert_stmt->execute(); will return TRUE when successfully executed, otherwise it will return FALSE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please debug you code step wise like this.

It will surely give your err, if you have.

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `alerte` (`nom_alerte`, `country`, `date_debut_alerte`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param('sss', $alert_name, $country, $start_alert_date)){
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}else {
    $reponse = 'success';
}
```

Once you get err. You can change your code accordingly later.

I hope this will help you to find your err easily!

Comment: @Nancy Thanks a lot for the answer. Actually the code is working fine. I wanted to know if it was a good way of coding or if there is a nicer (more elegant) way. Anyways thanks for taking the time to answer and showing me a nice way of debuging.

Comment: Great; I was actually saying nicely that you did not answered the question. Have a great day